# Regex to find if a reference to jQuery exists in inline script

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-greedy

i am trying to create a regex pattern that checks whether 'jQuery' exists anywhere between `<script>` and `</script>` tag.

example:

```
<script>

 function foo(jQuery){
   alert("i take jQuery in as a parameter!");
 }

</script>
```

I have come up with the following regex:

```
/(?s)(<script>.*?jQuery.*?<\/script>)/
```

this seems to work fine if there is only one script block, if there are multiple scripts (and one of them contains jQuery) then the regex matches everything between the first  `<script>`  and last `</script>` tag present within the text.

```
<script> <-- Match starts
  const i = "foo";
</script> <-- no jQuery referenced in this script block...

<p>Hi!</p>

<script>
 console.log(jQuery);
</script> <-- Match ends
```

it should be like this

```
<script> <-- Match starts
 console.log(jQuery);
</script> <-- Match ends

<script>
  const i = "foo";
</script>

<p>Hi!</p>

<script> <-- Match starts
 console.log(jQuery);
</script> <-- Match ends
```

Comment: You need to use a negative lookahead that prevents matching a `</script>` tag in between.

Comment: @Barmar im struggling to understand where to place the negative lookahead

Comment: Yeah, negative lookaheads are tricky. Do you have to do this with a single regexp? It would be easier if you used a regexp to find each script block, then just search for `jQuery` in each.

Comment: @Barmar im currently using the method of finding each script block then checking for jQuery in each block :) but was just curious to whether it was possible to do this in a single regexp

Comment: can you try this https://regex101.com/r/TyykDz/4/

Comment: @MuhammadNuman catastrophic backtracking error :(

Comment: how can I see this error?

Comment: @MuhammadNuman https://regex101.com/r/74IsUD/1/  script block with jQuery is at bottom.

Comment: You can use this: /(?s)(<script>(?:(?!<\/script>).)*?jQuery.*?<\/script>)/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use positive lookahead but without `(?s)`, something like

```
<script>.*?\r?\n?(?=jQuery)((?:.*?\r?\n?)*)<\/script>
```

<kbd>[Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/m17Gtu/5)</kbd>

Comment: this seems to be doing the opposite, its matching all script blocks that dont have jQuery, im trying to match all script blocks that do have jQuery